# Удаление строк с дубликатами букв

Tags: c#

Пожалуйста подскажите, к примеру есть массив из 4 строк

- ABCD
- ABCA
- ACCD
- ADCE

И нужно удалить  строки, циклом в которых найдены повторяющиеся символы, то есть нужно удалить строки под номерами 2 и 3.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: что, совсем никаких идей?

Comment: Сначала нужно найти такие строки. Затем их нужно удалить. С какой частью у Вас проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача распадается на две части, ключевая - понять, что строка имеет дубликаты букв.

Решать можно по-разному, вот лишь один вариант:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new [] {"ABCD", "ABCA", "ACCD", "ADCE"};
    var result = data.Where(x => !HasDups(x)).ToArray();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public bool HasDups(string sourse)
{
    return sourse.Length != sourse.Distinct().Count();
}
```

Во-первых, я не удаляю строки - а отбираю в результирующий IEnumerable, во-вторых, я определяю дубликат простым способом: длина строки совпадает с длиной Distinct.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также на большом so можно поискать вариации определения наличия дубликатов в строке без linq, вот [например](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21794359/5752652) очень быстрая (за O(n) в худшем случае) и простая реализация на HashSet'ах:

```
public bool HasDups(string sourse)
{
    var set = new HashSet<char>();

    foreach (var c in sourse)
    {
        if (!set.Add(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Distinct на самом деле тоже внутри с HashSet работает, правда второй вариант может пробегать не до конца, а только до первого совпадения, но на сложность алгоритма это не влияет - O(n) будет в обоих случаях, разница лишь в коэффициенте.